# Error in a c program to calculate the execution time of program

Tags: c, gcc, time

I'm trying to caculate the execution time of program given below but it is giving me some errors

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()

{
  clock_t start, end;   
  start = clock();


int a[5] ={1,2,3,4,51};
int b[5] = {2,3,4,5,6};
int c[5] = {3,4,5,6,7};


for (int i =0;i<5;i++)
{
    if(a[i]== NULL )
    printf("%d element null::",a[i]);
    else
    printf("no null values in first array\n");


        if(b[i]== NULL )
    printf("%d element null::",b[i]); 
        else 
        printf("no null values in second array\n");


        if(c[i]== NULL )
    printf("%d element null::",c[i]);
        else
        printf("no null values in third array\n");

}


  end = clock();
  printf("Start time: %i, End time: %i \n" start, end);

return 0;

}
```

following are the errors and warnings..

```
        [eshwar@localhost ~]$ gcc -std=c99 ab.c
ab.c: In function ‘main’:
ab.c:18:9: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
  if(a[i]== NULL )
         ^
ab.c:24:16: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
         if(b[i]== NULL )
                ^
ab.c:30:16: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
         if(c[i]== NULL )
                ^
ab.c:39:44: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘start’
   printf("Start time: %i, End time: %i \n" start, end);
```

and why is this warning given..because I think we can initialise array like this??

Comment: `printf("Start time: %i, End time: %i \n" start, end);`
should be

    `printf("Start time: %i, End time: %i \n", start, end);`

Comment: whats the difference between two?? both look same

Comment: Comma before `start`, after the format string.

Comment: yaa got it..silly mistake..but why is it giving the warnings??

Comment: `ints` can't be `NULL`. What do you want to do there?

Comment: I just wanted to check whether the array contains a null value...but I got it int array cannot have null value as if not initialise it will store the garbage value...

Comment: Yeah . The comparison with `NULL` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Notice that with such a fast program, timing may not be significant. Try to run it many times : the measured execution time will largely change from one run to another.

Comment: yea, you are right, actually I was comparing execution time of two programs ie a program with three for loops  and program with a single for loop and three if statement within it..for much larger arrays

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just want to know whether one of the numbers in the array is 0.
In this case you just have to change if(a[i]== NULL ) to if(a[i] == 0).(And the same with the other two)

As Cool guy already said there has to be a comma between the string and the start.

The programm will work then but the compiler will still complain about the diffrence between 'clock_t' and 'int'

So finally you can change the line to:

```
printf("Start time: %i, End time: %i \n", (int)start, (int)end);
```